# Selenium (Python) doesn't work (GPU process launch failed: error_code=2)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a code that runs perfectly in one of my pc's but in the other happens a lot of errors. I have no idea how to fix it and i need it to work.

```
import subprocess, sys
def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
    install("selenium")
    install("chromedriver_autoinstaller")

#Imports
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

navegador= webdriver.Chrome()
navegador.get("https://www.google.com")
```

When Google Chrome isn't already open the errors are:(1) GPU process launch failed: error_code=2; (2) GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.; (3) unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.

When Google Chrome is already open the error is: NameError: name 'navegador' is not defined